# Crop image to camera view frame width and height

Tags: android, react-native

I have an image which has the height and width:

> {width: 1944,height: 2592}

I have an overlay view which has the following:

> {x: 36, y: 141, width: 288, height: 166}

which is on top of a camera view. I am using ImageManipulator which is in expo package to crop the image based on the width height and dimensions of frame. Now when I crop the image I do not get the focused area of the frame being cropped when I pass

> {x: 36, y: 141, width: 288, height: 166}

Can you please tell me why or what is the mistake I have?

**Edit:**
Code I tried:

```
var ratio = this.state.overlay.width / this.state.capturedImage.width;
const cropped = await ImageManipulator.manipulate(uri, [
  {
      crop: {
      originX: this.state.overlay.x,
      originY: this.state.overlay.y,
      width:   this.state.overlay.width / ratio,
      height:  this.state.overlay.height / ratio
    }

  }

], {
    compress: 0.9,
    format: "jpeg",
    base64: true
  }).catch((err) => {
  console.log("Failed to crop image, details: " + err);
});
```

Comment: A code snippet, for what you've tried until now would be helpful

Comment: I have edited the post and added code sir, please have a look at it and let me know what is wrong. thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? I'm having the same issue on Android, although on iOS it works pretty well (using @react-native-community/image-editor).